# Is $g(x)=\cfrac{1}{1-\cfrac{1}{1-\cfrac{1}{1-x}}}$ continuous at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity, solution-verification

Is $$
g(x)=\cfrac{1}{1-\cfrac{1}{1-\cfrac{1}{1-x}}}
$$ continuous at $x=0$ ?

**My attempt $\rightarrow$**

I thought of an another function $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$$ and then with this $$f(f(f(x)))$$ I got the required function.

Then found that $$
f(f(x)
$$
Is not continuous at $x=0$

So $f(f(f(x)))=$ is also not continuous at $x=0$ .

This is what I know.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the function is not defined at $x=0$, so it has no sense to ask if it is continuous. Probably the question is : can the function be extended continuously through $0$...

Comment: All of your used functions are continuous on their domain. Hence, their composition is continuous on its domain. But $0$ is not in your domain. Your function is continuous, where it is well-defined.

Comment: Is it relevant that $g(x) = x$?

Comment: @ComptonScattering That is true only where $\;g\;$ is defined. It isn't at $\;x=0\;$ , as already explained elsewhere.

Comment: @Troposphere try again :)

Answer (score 2):

For it to be continous at a given point, left-limit right-limit and the value at that point should be equal.

Now that the value does not exist ($x=0$), can we talk about it in terms of being equal to something?

It is not continuous at $x=0$.